# Cannot fix height 100% of parent using floated elements inside

Tags: html, css

[image]
I need to fix height 100% of page-wrapper for the right-sidebar, main-contents and left sidebar. Any idea..? Below is my css file too. I have used a class named clearfix in page-wrapper but height is not fixed.The 100% is not accurate though since I need header and footer-wrapper to appear as well..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>e-support-uop</title>

    <!-- styling files  -->

    <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="clearfix">
        <div id="header">0</div>
        <div id="left_sidebar">
            <br/>
            1
        </div> <!--end left_sidebar -->

        <div id="main_contents">
            <br/>
            2
        </div>
        <div id="right_sidebar">
            <br/>
            3
        </div> <!--close right_sidebar -->
        <div id="footer-wrapper"> <!-- footer -->
            4
        </div> <!-- end footer -->
    </div><!--close page-wrapper-->
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my css file:

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.clearfix{
   min-height: 1%;
   _height: 1%;   /*ie6*/
}

.clearfix:after{
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:#d2c7fd;
  font-size:14px;
}

#page-wrapper {
  position: relative;

  background-color: #E4E6EB;
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 80%;
  height: auto !important;
  margin: 5px auto 0;
}

#header {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
 }

#left_sidebar {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100%; /*height: auto !important;

  */

  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#main_contents {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 55%;
  height: 90%; /*height: auto !important;

  /* height: 100%;
   */
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px; /*background-color: red;
  */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /*display: table-row;*/
  overflow:hidden;
}

#right_sidebar {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%; /*background-color: yellow;
  */
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#footer-wrapper {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-100px;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #d8d8d6;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #E0E0E0;
  /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
}
```

Comment: Can you post an image of what the layout is suppose to look like?  It is not clear what you are trying to do since the HTML that you presented can be styled several ways depending on what you are trying to achieve.  Thank you.

Comment: I can t Mrc Audet. Ineed at least 10 reputation....:(

Comment: Here is the confusing point.  It looks like you want: #left_sidebar, #main_contents and #right_sidebar to be 100% of the height of #page-wrapper.  However, if that is the case, where are #header and #footer-wrapper suppose to go? Or do you mean the following: let  #left_sidebar, #main_contents and #right_sidebar take up the vertical space of the viewport after allowing for the height of the header and footer? Please clarify your post and make it clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I think I made it more clear...Any idea now..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

I made a slight modification to your HTML by adding a `.main-wrap` to wrap the floats.

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="header">0</div>
    <div id="main-wrap">
        <div id="left_sidebar">1</div><!--end left_sidebar -->
        <div id="main_contents">2</div>
        <div id="right_sidebar">3</div><!--end right_sidebar -->
    </div><!-- end main-wrap -->
    <div id="footer-wrapper">4</div><!-- end footer -->
</div><!--close page-wrapper-->
```

and here is the CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#page-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px; /* optional */
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
 }
#main-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 105px;
    bottom: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#left_sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

#main_contents {
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}

#right_sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#footer-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #d8d8d6;
}
```

See demo fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xMNUv/

The trick is to extend the `#page-wrapper` to the full height of the view port.  Set the top and bottom margin to zero to prevent vertical scrolling.

The `#header` and `#footer-wrapper` are both 100px in height, so you can now use absolute positioning to stretch the `main-wrap` to fill up the space between the header and footer elements.

You can use `position: relative` on the header to open up some white space on top if you need it.

Within the `#main-wrap`, you can now float your sidebars and content elements to form a 3-column layout.  Apply `height: 100%` to get the floated elements to fill up the `#main-wrap` height.

You may want to add a minimum height value to `#page-wrapper` to prevent the columns from collapsing.

Depending on your content, your floated columns may overflow since their height is constrained by the height of the view port.  You may want to add `overflow: auto` to the floated elements as needed.

Comment: That s cool Mark but when i try to add some text in main comtents div it does not extend..any solution to that..?

Comment: The design you requested will not extend since you wanted the header, floated columns and footer to fit within the 100% view port.  If you want the design to extend beyond the view port, you need to allow the `#page-wrapper` height to be auto, and decide what to do about the footer.  Alternatively, you can set `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` on `.main-wrap`, but then you need to adjust the width of your floated elements to deal with the width of the scroll bar. You will also need to rethink about how the heights of the floated columns adjust themselves when you start to add content.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this unless you set a fixed height on the parent element, which probably you don't want.

If you don't care about IE 7 and below, you might want to use

```
display: table-cell
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fikct